# How can i move Caret to Last index in TextBox or RichTextBox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have a TextBox or RichTextBox

How can i move Caret to Last index in TextBox or RichTextBox?

Comment: You can use the AppendText method for TextBox in order to automatically move the Caret to the last index of the text just after adding it.

Answer (score 2):

To Move Caret to the Last Index in a TextBox or a RichTextBox Use this Code:

For TextBox

```
TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
```

For RichTextBox

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
```

Comment: This doesn't select the last word. This does: `dim txtBox = DirectCast(richTextBox1 as TextBoxBase) dim lastSpace = txtBox.Text.LastIndexOf(" "c) + 1 txtBox.Select(lastSpace, txtBox.TextLength - lastSpace)`. For a TextBox, just change `dim txtBox = DirectCast(textBox1 as TextBoxBase)`. All those methods belong to the base class, `TextBoxBase`. Missing fine-tuning to remove punctuation, if any or required.

Comment: I'm Sure this select last word

Comment: No, it doesn't. That just moves the caret to the last position (only because it cannot move any further). Moreover, the line index is irrelevant in this calculation.

Comment: To move the caret to the last position, you just need `TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength`. As already mentioned, the line index is irrelevant and the RichTextBox and TextBox Controls both derive from TextBoxBase, so you need one method for any of those, using the cast in my first comment (in case you need to have a method for this).

Comment: omg i know this but i'm working with so many projects, Sorry i edited my answer again.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the point of asking the question if you know the answer? Do you think this will be of value to future readers?